# Why doesn't aria-labelledby fetch values for a div from outside of it?

Tags: html, accessibility

So I am trying to access a label for a div that is focusable via `tabIndex`. However, for some reason (since the label is outside the div), the label is not being fetched.

However, the label is being fetched for an input that has the same `aria-labelledby`. Any idea how I can get my div to fetch from outside of itself similar to the input?

Obviously if I include the label inside the div, it works.

Code can be seen here:
https://jsfiddle.net/b1ca7tm9/1/

I want the div to also fetch labels outside of itself.

FYI: You can view/hear the label being read/displayed for the input but not for the div. You can verify this via voiceover on mac, or NVDA on windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the code you provided the most likely issue is that even though you have made the div focusable with tabindex it's role is still a div which is a non-interactive element.

While the ARIA spec implies that aria-labelledby can be used on any element, in practice most screen readers and browsers only honor it for interactive elements and select non-interactive elements. This is because aria-labelledby will be read by the screen reader instead of the content of the element, which in most cases would not be good for screen reader users.

If the element receives focus, it's most likely intended to be interactive, so the fix would be to give it an [aria role](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-1.1/#usage_intro) that corresponds with its intended functionality (e.g button). If it's truly non-interactive, it should probably not be in the tab order. If you provide some more context about the purpose of the div, I could give some more detailed advice on what role would be best

On another note, tabindex="0" is usually better than declaring a specific position in the tab order. Tabindex="0" will allow the element to receive focus, but doesn't force a specific position (it will just fit into the tab order wherever it would if it were natively focus-able). This way you don't have to go around adding tabindexes to every interactive element on the page

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. 
The role is to take users to a portion of the app (to a message), and then have a label be announced to the reader that a specific portion of the app is reached.

However, since there are many messages in the app, I will not trigger that label on each message, and only want to trigger it when the user presses f6.

Which is why I cannot include the label within the message, or else it will be duplicated in each message.

I want an h1 to just live somewhere in the parent of the message list, and then have the message read it out (only if the f6 key is used).

Comment: The user can then also interact with the message, and the actions attributed to each message. I want these messages divs to be focusable since there is a lot of content in them, and I want to give users to ability to jump through messages instead of tabbing repeatedly to jump between messages.

Comment: So, you might want to look at a few alternatives to this approach. For instance having the screen reader read something when a key like f6 is pressed might be better accomplished with an aria-live region such as alert

Comment: Also there might be better ways to handle navigating between messages, such as with headings (screen readers can jump between headings natively). Its not clear to me how making the messages focusable makes it easier for people to navigate since it adds extra tabs (meaning they will have to press more tabs rather than less). If this is an element you want a button to jump people to but it not be in the tab order you can use tabindex="-1"